# how to print star icon in a pattern in react js that filter users according to stars(reputation)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

i want to print star icon in react js as in first line 1 and in 2nd line 2 stars likewise.

I tried

```
  const [userList, setUsersList] = useState([]);
  const [starClicked, setStarClicked] = useState();
  return (
   <div className="App">
     {[...Array(5)].map((star, idx) => {
       return (
         <p key={idx} onClick={() => setStarClicked(idx + 1)}>
           <StarOutlinedIcon />
         </p>
       );
     })}

    {starClicked
    ? userList
        .filter((d) => d.stars === starClicked)
        .map((d) => {
          return <li key={d._id}> {d.userName} </li>;
        })
    : userList.map((d) => {
        return <li key={d._id}> {d.userName} </li>;
      })}
```

this does the filtering part great but printing only 5 stars in a vertical line. I want to print like 1 star in 1 line, 2 stars in 2nd line likewise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another looping to render the stars according to their index:

```
{[...Array(5)].map((star, idx) => {
    const actualIndex = idx + 1;

    return (
        <p key={idx} onClick={() => setStarClicked(actualIndex)}>
            {[...Array(actualIndex)].map((_, starIdx) => (
                <StarOutlinedIcon key={starIdx} />
            ))}
        </p>
    );
})}
```